# a:hover - using images in text navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code my navigation on my portfolio and am looking for a simpler way of doing this than using background position and css sprites.

Basically I want navigation similar to that of this website: http://www.ernesthemingwaycollection.com/ where when you hover over the navigation, a bar appears below it.

Is there a simpler way of doing this or do I have to use background positioning.

Btw, I have used text as my navigation and would rather keep it that way instead of using images for the navigation. I only want to use images for the hover image. I have tried to do this simply by using the following code:

```
#nav a:hover {
background: url('Images/Nav_Hover.png') no-repeat;
}
```

However, I can't seem to position the image? Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you mean "position the image"? Can you clarify that at all?  providing an position to `background` or using `background-position` separately is how to move the background in the element, but I'm not sure exactly what problem you're having from the description.

Comment: Sorry. I mean the Nav_Hover.png image. I can't seem to change its position on the page, by margin's etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav a:hover { 
  background: url('Images/Nav_Hover.png') no-repeat 10px 20px; 
}
```

Where `10px` is the horizontal positioning and `20px` the vertical.
Or just use `background-position` as mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a sprite, though it's usually more efficient for several reasons.

You can just use an entirely different image, for example:

```
a { background: url('image.jpg'); }
a:hover { background: url('image-hover.jpg'); }
```

Be warned that there may be a slight delay in the hover as it loads the image the first time (for remote users, you won't notice this locally with no latency)...so you may want to pre-load these hover images. This is something that sprites by nature take care of, so don't *completely* toss them out as an option...there are resources to help creating them if that's the concern.

Comment: As Nick mentioned, there is a delay and preloading also increases the number of HTTP requests your browser makes, slowing down your load times.

Answer (score 0):

To anwser your question, i think using 1 image with the normal and hover state in it, is not only the easy way, but also the very best way.
No preload / delay issues, no browser issues (except for hover not working in ie6).

Sprites for navigation is pretty easy. The positioning is a Bia*** when you use it for all images. Make the hover image as wide as you're widest link, and a little css will do everything.

```
a.navLink { background:url(image) no-repeat; /* and ofcourse witdh and stuffs */ }
a.navlink:hover { background-position:0px -20px; /* height of button */ }
```

I dont think it can be easier.. A different way is using javacript, but i wouldn't do that for a hover.